# Java - Strings and one dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, dimensional

I want to examine a sequence of strings, compute the average string length, and count how many strings are above the average length.

So far, in my code, it only reads ints, and a string also has characters. So how do I change my code so that it works for strings and not int. I know that the first step is take out the nextInt methods and change it to work for strings as well as the other int variables in the code. Can someone help me?

```
// examine a sequence of strings 
// compute the average string length
// count how many strings are above the average length

import java.util.*;

public class StringArrayTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What is the number of strings? ");
    int numStrings = console.nextInt();
    String[] strings = new String[numStrings];

    // record strings to find average length
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
        System.out.println("Number of strings from string " + (i + 1) + ": ");
        String nextLine = console.next();
        strings[i] = nextLine;
        sum += strings[i].length;
    }
    double average = (double) sum / numStrings;

    // count strings above average length
    int above = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            if (strings[i].length() > average) {
                 above++;
            }
        }

        // report results
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Average length of strings: " + average);
        System.out.println(above + " strings above average length");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only changes are being posted here. Rest of the code remains the same.

1. Data type of array is changed from int to String
2. console.nextInt() changed to console.next() which will read a String on return
3. Loop through the String array and compare the length of individual strings against the average of length of the strings.

That's all that is required.

```
String[] strings = new String[numStrings];
...
for (int i = 0; i < numStrings; i++) {
            System.out.println("Number of strings from string " + (i + 1) + ": ");
            String nextLine = console.next();
            strings[i] = nextLine;
            sum += strings[i].length();
        }
...
for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
            if (strings[i].length() > average) {
                above++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Edited original code with the changes you said. Still not working. Please see my edits in the code now above

Comment: w00t!! You have to assign the String that you have read into the array and then use it. strings[i] = nextLine; seems to be missing in your code.

Comment: I have to use the Scanner method next() instead of nextLine() to get the strings

Comment: What is not working? What is the problem that you are facing? I have same piece of code working! Also we are using next() method, see console.next();

Comment: My code is exactly as it is in the post right now. It is the most updated, all the errors I'm getting is symbol cannot be found. There's like 20 of those errors.

Comment: You are missing braces for length method on a String, here - `strings[i].length();`

Answer (score -1):

you could change the following
change
    `console.nextInt()` 
to 
   `console.nextLine()`

`sum += strings[i]`
to 
    `sum += strings[i].length`

`if (strings[i] > average)`
to 
    `if (strings[i].length > average)`

Comment: Does this work if I use method next() instead of nextLine()?

Comment: @m.daooo it would work if the the strings you use do not contain whitespaces in them (i.e. spaces, tabs and so on)

Comment: nextLine will get everything up to \n(when the user hits enter)

Comment: I'm not allowed to use nextLine() method

Comment: I have to use the Scanner method next() instead of nextLine() to get the strings